# How can I install "ethernet" for Lenovo T430s?

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, ethernet

it finally happened I'm done with USB-C to Ethernet on my Dell XPS and set up my old T430s which has an ethernet port with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. All I do with that machine is router configurations, that's why I'm trying to use the ethernet port (wifi works but it won't help for my purposes.

If anyone knows how I can get ethernet enable in Ubuntu for the Lenovo T430s please let me know and again I do not wish to use any adapters.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Best regards,
KingsleyMidas

Comment: If it has an Ethernet port, you shouldn't have to do anything special. Of course you will need to connect to any network you wish to join so you may need to speak with a network administrator in some cases, especially if they employ MAC filtering.  If you have a problem you would like us to review, you will need to provide details about that problem. Start by telling us the make/model of the Ethernet adapter as well as detailed account of what you've tried so far and the details of each attempt

Comment: Yeah that's the weird thing when I type - iwconfig the eth won't even show up but its enabled in the bios

Answer (score 1):

> All I do with that machine is router configurations

I suggest that you connect the ethernet cable to a LAN port on the router. Find the address of the router from the user guide or Google fu. For example, the router I configured yesterday was 192.168.8.1.

On the Ubuntu machine, from the terminal:

```
ip addr show
```

Find the interface name for the ethernet; for example enp0s25.

Back to the terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig enp0s25 192.168.8.2 up
```

Open a browser and navigate to http://192.168.8.1

The administration page of the router should appear.

Of course, substitute your details for those above.

Comment: Well yeah, I'm trying to use the Lan Port but ethernet doesn't show up as an option in terminal with iwconfig so I assume that I need to install the driver manually? Ethernet card is intel pro 1000 LAN

Comment: `iwconfig` exposes wireless interfaces. I suggested `ifconfig.`

Comment: oh yeah thanks.. so even with ifconfig I'm only getting loopback and wifi wlp3s0 no ethernet :(  maybe I really need to pull the trigger on a new machine....

Comment: What does this tell us? `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: HI Chili555, "lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3" no return but "lspci -nnk | grep 0300 -A3" Network Controller {280} Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced -N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (34), kernel driver in use: iwlwifi, kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: 0200 is the class for ethernet. You might check every line of: `lspci -nnk` and see if you see ethernet. If not, I suspect a hardware issue.

Comment: Hi Chili555, unless I'm blind it only shows the wlan adapter 3:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n) [8086:1311]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Comment: Above,you said; "Ethernet card is intel pro 1000 LAN" Where did you see that? In Ubuntu, Windows or the laptop's specs? If `lspci` shows no ethernet card, then my strong suspicion is that the hardware has failed.

Comment: FYI, my similar T440p shows: Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM [8086:153a] (rev 04) etc. Notice the [0200] in the listing. That's what we grepped for in the command.